# Conky forecast F C output

Tags: conky

```
Temp: ${execi 3600 conkyForecast --location=01104  --imperial datatype=HT}
```

This what I have and it shows the right temp but it says 25° AF.

Any help or hints appreciated

And as allways TYAVMIA

Answer (score 1):

If you use --hidedegreesymbol option and the A goes away, then it's probably because the degree symbol is being incorrectly converted to/from utf8.

OTOH if you use --hideunits and the A goes away, then it's likely a bug in the system.

Either way you should report the issue to the conkyForecast creator Kaivalagi to try and get a fix. Because either way it's hard to use.

Answer (score 0):

To get temperatures, I prefer to use a combination of curl, grep, sed, and awk to get my data.  Here is a copy of the relevant section of my conky setup (currently configured to display weather for Trenton, NJ...so you will need to alter that to make it usable for your part of the world).

```
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ Weather monitoring
${voffset 6}${color purple}Weather (KTTN):${alignr}${color}${execi 3600 curl -s http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/decoded/KTTN.TXT | grep "Weather" | cut -c10-100 | sed 's/;/ and/g'} 
 ${voffset -1}${color purple}Temp C: ${alignr 157}${color}${execi 3600 curl -s http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/decoded/KTTN.TXT | grep "Temperature" | awk '{print $4}' | cut -c2-100}°C
 ${voffset -15}${color purple}                      Temp F: ${alignr}${color}${execi 3600 curl -s http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/decoded/KTTN.TXT | grep "Temperature" | awk '{print $2}'}°F 
 ${voffset -2}${color purple}Dew Point C: ${alignr 157}${color}${execi 3600 curl -s http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/decoded/KTTN.TXT | grep "Dew Point" | awk '{print $5}' | cut -c2-100}°C
 ${voffset -15}${color purple}                      Dew Point F: ${alignr 7}${color}${execi 3600 curl -s http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/decoded/KTTN.TXT | grep "Dew Point" | awk '{print $3}'}°F${endif}
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
```

This will give you the current weather conditions, temperature in celsius and fahrenheit, and dewpoints in the same dual format.